# How to crash Jboss based on some condition

Tags: performance, jboss, jvm, byteman

I am using JBoss 7x, and have the following use case.

I am going to do load testing of messaging queues with Jboss. The queues are external to JBoss.

I will push a lot of message in the queue, around 1000 message. When around 100+ message has been pushed I want to crash JBoss. Later I want to re-start the Jboss the verify the message processing.

I had earlier made use of Byteman to crash the JVM using the following

JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:/BYTEMAN_HOME/lib/byteman.jar=script:/QUICKSTART_HOME/jta-crash-rec/src/main/scripts/xa.btm ${JAVA_OPTS}"

Details are here: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/7.3.x/jta-crash-rec

In the above case when ever XA Transaction is happening the JVM is being crashed using byteman, but in my case I want to only crash the JVM/Jboss lets say after 100+ messages. i.e not for each transaction but after processing some messages.

I have also tried a few examples from here, to get ideas of how to achieve it, but did not succeed. https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-17213#top

**Question**: How can I crash JBoss/ running JVM using byteman or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

See the Programmers Guide that comes bundled with the distribution.
Sections headed "CountDowns" and  "Aborting Execution" provide what's necessary. These are built-in features of the Rule Language.